# How to determine if a cell background is a specified RGB color?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through cells in Excel that if it finds 2 cell backgrounds in a specified RGB color then show a message.

I have `MsgBoxStop.Show` because is a Form that I am calling, but it is fine if I use `MsgBox "your message"`

```vb
Dim counter As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim total As Integer
total = 0

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B58:B61").Cells
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(218, 150, 148) Then
        total = total + 1
        If total = 2 Then
            MsgBoxStop.Show
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: `MsgBox "Stop"` maybe?

Comment: Change `MsgBoxStop.Show` to `MsgBox "some message"`. The code won't go further until the user clicks "OK". If you want to get out of the sub immediately afterwards, just follow up with `Exit Sub` in the next line.

Comment: I have MsgBoxStop.Show because is a Form that I am calling, but it is fine if I use MsgBox "your message" I don't mind at all, but it still not working for me either way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message after find two cells with a RGB(218,150,148), you need to replace **MsgBoxStop.Show** to **MsgBox "your message", vbInformation, "Your title**

If total = 2 Then
MsgBox "2 RGB(218,150,148) has be found", vbInformation, "TestCode"
cell.activate
Exit For
End If

Comment: I have MsgBoxStop.Show because is a Form that I am calling, but it is fine if I use MsgBox "your message" I don't mind at all, but it still not working for me either way

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that when using Conditional Formatting in excel, you cant use (cell.Interior.Color) you would have to use (cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color).

My code works perfectly now!

```
     Dim counter As Integer
     Dim cell As Range
     counter = 0

     For Each cell In Range("B60:B63")
         If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
             counter = counter + 1
             If counter = 2 Then
                  MsgBox "Stop!"
             End If
         End If
     Next cell
```